# Reading console input from VC++ 2008 compiler :Error

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I am using this simple..yet getting error.

to read a directory path from console window and then printing the path in window..

please do check why am getting unhandled exception error:

Error:Unhandled exception at 0x1029984f (msvcr90d.dll) in new_one.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x745c3a46.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_PATH_LENGTH 256 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int i;
int pathlength=100;
char *path=(char *)malloc(MAX_PATH_LENGTH);
free(path);
printf("Enter the path:");
scanf("%s",&path); 
printf("%s",path);
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Still i get the sam eexception..please give me any suggestion

Comment: why are you freeing the memory allocated for `path` as the next step? It would be appropriate to free the memory for `path` after you are done with it. That is, in your program it would be right before you `return 0;`

Comment: Thanks for the reply...but i get the same unhnadled exception..any idea to solve it..?

Comment: Its high time you learn to use a debugger and step through the code yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *path;
```

Is not allocated any memory. You are writing to an unallocated pointer variable resulting in **Undefined Behavior**, which shows up as an segmentation fault.

You could solve the problem in two ways:

### Allocating object on stack:

Create `path` as an array locally on stack, such as:

```
#define MAX_PATH_LENGTH 256

char path[MAX_PATH_LENGTH];
```

### Dynamic Memory allocation:

```
#define MAX_PATH_LENGTH 256

char *path=(char *)malloc(MAX_PATH_LENGTH);
```

If you use the second approach, You need to explicitly, `free` the allocated memory after your usage:

```
free(path);
```

Usually, avoid using dynamic allocations(second approach) unless the memory requirement is too large to be allocated on stack.

Comment: The cast for the return value of `malloc` is, at best, redundant; and (as in the provided code) it may hide an error the compiler would have caught otherwise.

Comment: Just now i changed the code mentioned above still the same unhandled exception

Comment: @hari: You should call the `free()` after your usage of `path` is done.Right now you allocate memory to `path` and in the very next statement you deallocate it using `free()`, this leaves your pointer with no memory and the same situation as in the original problem.Call `free()` just before `return 0;`

Comment: @hari: Also, `scanf("%s",&path);` should be `scanf("%s",path);`, notice the absence of `&` in front of `path`. Also, I am going to suggest to pick up a good book and learn the fundamentals.You need a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn the language not online tutorials or blogs.

Comment: Hi if i use the char[256]; it will show the directory path of one folder only eg:F:\test.If i use the path as F:\test\tools it doersnot show any thing.Why am getting unhandled exception if i use dynamic memory allocation procedure